# How do I make Flex create one-element arrays from XML data?

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I retrieve XML data in Flex via HttpService. I have the `resultFormat` property on the HttpService instance set to `HTTPService.RESULT_FORMAT_OBJECT`. The result contains data similar to this:

```
<!-- ... -->
<children>
  <item><!-- ... --></item>
  <item><!-- ... --></item>
  <!-- ... -->
<children>
<!-- ... -->
```

I get an array named item beneath the element children when there is more than one `item` sibling. If there's only one, the conversion can't distinguish it from a scalar.

What do I need to change to have Flex convert all `item` elements to an array with 0 or more elements?

What would I have to do to get an array member `children`, dropping the `item` wrappers altogether?

The XML is generated by Struts on the server side. I always have the option to change the structure of the document there, but right now I'm interested in what I can do with Flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `item` object should be an `XMLList` whether there is one entry or several.  (It will be `undefined` if there are none.)

You can use `XML` methods on it if there is only one element, but that's just as a convenience.  See the [XMLList documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/XMLList.html).

I also recommend comment 5 on this [blog entry](http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:eZmaHl2yM3IJ:www.morearty.com/blog/2007/03/13/common-e4x-pitfalls/+e4x+actionscript+xmllist&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a) by Mike Morearty (cached version as the site appears to be inaccessible).

Comment: That link is nice. So, the basic takeaway then is to use e4x results, right?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
try {
    for (var i:int = 0; /* loop forever till error is thrown */; i++) {
        var j:String = String( children.item[ i ].SomeOtherAttribute ); // if its a string
    }
} catch (re:RangeError) {
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. What's that code supposed to do? Also, allow me to frown on what seems a slight abuse of exceptions. (If I can do item[i], sure there's item.length to be used for a loop condition, no?)

Comment: I encountered this problem while building a prototype. The length attribute wasn't there. After a couple of minutes I thought of this solution and it worked fine. I never said "This is the perfect solution", just "Try this". I needed to get past this problem as quickly as possible. And I couldn't come to SO, ask a question and then a wait for an answer. Hence, I used what worked for me.

If the prototype works & people like it, then I can think about making it production ready, and then I can replace this code with something much better. Till then, I see no need to worry about purity.